# row doesn't get deleted in mysql when I use mysql workbench but when i use it from the terminal application, it does

Tags: mysql

when I use the query "delete from passwords.passwords where website = 'nowebsite';" it gets deleted in terminal but when I execute the exact same thing in the workbench it doesn't. How can I fix this?

Comment: Dont forget to run the query in workbench, it only shows the result, you actually have to run the query in workbench.

Comment: @Grumpy of course I run my query in workbench.